# Exercise 66 of chapter 11 in Spivak calculus

Tags: calculus

Exercise 66 of chapter 11 in Spivak calculus, asks to show that (a) $f$ has a local minimum at $0$ and (b) prove that $f'(0)=f''(0)=0$ for the function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^4\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)&\text{for $x\not=0$}\\
0&\text{for $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
I have done these two parts and I am ok with it. However at the end of this question, there is a comment that I do not understand a part of this comment (I have written the part that I do not understand in bold).

> This function thus provides another example to show that theorem 6 can
>   not be improved. It also illustrates a subtlety about maxima and
>   minima that often goes unnoticed; **a function may not be increasing
>   in any interval to the right of a local minimum point, nor decreasing
>   in any interval to the left**.

Could someone please clarify this for me? and here is theorem 6.

**Theorem 6.** Suppose $f''(a)$ exists. If $f$ has a local minimum at $a$, then $f''(a)\geq0$; if $f$ has a local maximum at $a$, then $f''(a)\leq0$.

Comment: How does Spivak define the term "local minimum"?

Comment: Also, how did you show that it is a minimum? Presumably you had to calculate the derivatives first, so why are two of them asked for in the second part of the question?

Comment: For the first part, you do not really need derivatives; $f(0)=0$ and so $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus $0$ is a minimum for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well clearly such a definition of minimum implies his claim. For example, the constant function $f(x)=c$ has a local min everywhere, but is not increasing or decreasing on either side of those minima. Still, did you happen to compute higher-order derivatives? I would be interested to know what they come out to.

Comment: Show that $\sin^2(1/x)$ is not monotonic in any interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ by showing the derivative changes sign at infinitely many points.

Comment: @NotNotLogical Good point, but $f(x) = c$ isn't quite as good of an example because it is both increasing and decreasing on both sides of the minima, just not *strictly* increasing or decreasing.  This function $f$ is not even increasing or decreasing at all.

Comment: Does anyone know what the first non-zero derivative is for this function? It seems to provide a counter-example to the higher-order derivative test (when suitable conditions are not met).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help you to look at the graph of $f$:

[image]

At any value of $x = \frac{1}{k\pi}$ for some $k$, the graph is zero.  So it is clear that despite having a local minimum at $0$ (defining "local minimum" to include the non-strict inequality $f(0) \le f(x)$), $f$ is not increasing or decreasing in any interval to the left or right.  Here I'm using "increasing" to be non-strict, so it means $a < b$ implies $f(a) \le f(b)$.  Similarly for decreasing.